# Solving a differential equation with three variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking at the differential equation:

$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = \sqrt{\frac{k^2}{R}+k^2\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{R}\right)} $$

where $k$ is a positive constant.

I'm not sure how to solve this for r(t) with three different variables and the radical over everything?

Comment: k is for sure. I'm not sure about R. The question doesn't specifically state so. I'm assuming that it isn't.

However, it is certainly a possibility that R is a constant. The equation is modeling a projectile launched vertically from the surface of the earth.

Comment: Isn't R the radius of the Earth? If this is the case, all you need do is separate the DEQ $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dr}{\sqrt{\dfrac{k^2}{R}+k^2\left(\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{R}\right)}} = \int dt$. Also, if you expand what is under the radical, you have the $k^2/R$ cancel. Are you sure you wrote it properly?

Comment: Wow, that's it. I didn't even realize that k^2/R cancels. This is a straight forward integration now. Knowing whether R is a constant or not didn't even matter. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, this integration doesn't seem so simple. Do I have to do some sort of u substitution?

Comment: Please see my answer, we just have $u^{1/2} du$. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, you DEQ is:

$$\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \sqrt{\dfrac{k^2}{R}+k^2\left(\dfrac{1}{r}-\dfrac{1}{R}\right)}$$

If that is written correctly (please check your original), this reduces to:

$$\dfrac{dr}{dt} = \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{r}}$$

This equation is separable and can be written in integral form (as you will see, we have the form $u^{1/2}~du$) as:

$$\displaystyle \int \sqrt{r} ~dr = k~ \int dt$$

This reduces to:

$$r(t) = \left( \dfrac{3}{2} \left(kt + c\right)\right)^{2/3}$$

Comment: You're on a roll today! Needs a TU +1

Comment: @amWhy: I almost think something was written incorrectly in the original problem as terms are canceling under the radical and that seems odd.

Comment: Thank you! You make it look very easy.

Comment: @Bob: You are very welcome, keep at it and you will get there too! Regards

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{k^2}{R} + k^2(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{R}) = \frac{k^2}{R} + \frac{k^2}{r} - \frac{k^2}{R} = \frac{k^2}{r}$$

No more $R$

Comment: I don't see where R was removed from the equation? Not sure how you arrived at this either.

Comment: I just used distributive property. I've added intermediate step, hope that helps